# When I dblclick, it runs .click twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 functions when you click on an item, .click and .dblclick
The problem is, that when you dblclick, it runs the .click function twice.
Is there a way to fix this?

```
$(".item").click(function() {
    if (price[this.id] === 1) {
        consoleUpdate("This item is worth " +price[this.id]+ " coin");
    }
}

$("#fishItem").unbind("dblclick").bind("dblclick").dblclick(function() {
    coins = coins+1;
    coinUpdate();
    invFish1--;
    if (invFish1 === 0) {
        $("#fishItem").appendTo("#itemStage");
    }
});
```

Comment: post your code or set up a fiddle.

Comment: *This is another annoying problem I'm having.* What's the other one? By the way, show us your code. We can't do magic here.

Comment: ["It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the click and dblclick events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies from browser to browser, with some receiving two click events before the dblclick and others only one."](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

Comment: note: isn't the whole point of jQuery to masks these differences across browsers?

Comment: Look at comment link of Blazemonger, simply don't do it, refactor your code and UI

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I choose to believe that the jQuery developers are smart enough to have solved this problem already, if it was solvable.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't think that is the point of jQuery... At least I would say that it aims to  extend browsers' functionality more or less _harmoniously_. Although, many times it also does fulfill that awesome purpose. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If you see an answer that suits your needs, don't forget to [mark it as correct](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the jQuery documentation for the dblclick event:

> It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the click and dblclick
>   events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies
>   from browser to browser, with some receiving two click events before
>   the dblclick and others only one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum
>   time between clicks that is detected as a double click) can vary by
>   operating system and browser, and is often user-configurable.

You want to change your events so that you don't have a `.click` and `.dblclick` on the same element.

http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is the easiest solution is to make it shift click

Answer (score 1):

```
var cnt=1;
$( "#target" ).click(function(e) {

if(cnt==1)
{

// action on single click if you dont want anything in in single click then use here
e.preventDefault();

}else{

// work on double click
cnt=1;// again set counter 
}

cnt++;
});
```

reference [e.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: this algo worked for me. in my case though i want thing to happen on single click, and none on double click (when cnt==2), so i just return false on else. :) thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, you can't really bind both click and double click to the same item.  There are, however, workarounds.

One way to handle this would be to handle the click code and then check for double-click:

```
var lastClickTime = 0;
$(".item").click(function() {
    var thisClickTime = (new Date).getTime();

    if (thisClickTime - lastClickTime < 500) {
        //Double-click
    }
    else {
        //Click
    }
    lastClickTime = thisClickTime;
});
```

This code essentially captures a "last click time" and if this click time is less than 500 milliseconds from the last click time, then it fires the double-click code.  Otherwise it will fire the click code.

The downside with this is that the click-code will be called first and then the double-click code.  Also, you're forcing your users into a 500ms double-click. While this is pretty standard, it's not guaranteed.  (Slower clickers may have trouble with this.)

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6qcT/) that demonstrates this technique.

---

You could improve this code by setting a 500ms timeout for the click code and then cancelling the click event if a double-click is fired.  The downside with this is that it will force a 500 ms delay between the click and the "click" code.

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6qcT/1/) that demonstrates the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind handling one single-click, look at the event object details attribute. It is the number of clicks.

```
$(".item").click(function(event) {
    if (event.details === 1) {
        //handle single click
    } else if (event.details === 2) {
        // handle double click
    }
}
```

Comment: [Juan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53753800/2391667) is a great workaround, however I believe it should be `event.detail` (singular). **UIEvent.detail:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail